# Looking for an explanation of function composition

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

I am reading this [tutorial on Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/functions.html). They define *function composition* as the following:

```
(.)                     :: (b->c) -> (a->b) -> (a->c)
f . g                   = \ x -> f (g x)
```

No examples were provided, which I believe would enlighten me as to what is being defined here.

Can someone provide a simple example (with explanation) of how function composition is used?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Function composition is a way to "compose" two functions together into a single function. Here's an example:

Say you have these functions:

```
even :: Int -> Bool
not :: Bool -> Bool
```

and you want to define your own `myOdd :: Int -> Bool` function using the two above.

The obvious way to do this is the following:

```
myOdd :: Int -> Bool
myOdd x = not (even x)
```

But this can be done more succinctly using function composition:

```
myOdd :: Int -> Bool
myOdd = not . even
```

The `myOdd` functions behave exactly the same, but the second one is created by "glue-ing" two functions together.

A scenario where this is especially useful is to remove the need for an explicit lambda. E.g:

```
map (\x -> not (even x)) [1..9]
```

can be rewritten to:

```
map (not . even) [1..9]
```

A bit shorter, less room for errors.

Comment: How come you don't need to show the input parameter in the definition? For instance. how come you don't write `myOdd x = not . even x`?

Comment: @unclerojelio It's called point-free style. Rather than define `myOdd` in terms of the result for a given argument ("Given `x`, `myOdd` returns the same value as `(not . even) x`"), it is defined in terms of what it actually is ("`myOdd` is the function that results when `not` is composed with `even`").

Answer (score 45):

Fun side note. Function composition is the equivalent of a syllogism in logic:

> All men are mortal. Socrates is a man. Therefore, Socrates is mortal.

A syllogism composes two material implications into one:

```
(Man => Mortal), (Socrates => Man), therefore (Socrates => Mortal)
```

Therefore...

```
(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

... which is the type of the `.` function.

Answer (score 17):

The *composition* of `f` and `g` is a function that first applies `g` to its argument, then `f` to the value returned by `g`. It then returns the return value of `f`.

This identity may be enlightening:

```
f (g x) = (f . g) x
```

If you have a Java/C background, consider this example:

```
int f(int x);
int g(int x);
int theComposition(int x) { return f(g(x)); }
```

Answer (score 8):

This example is contrived, but suppose we have

```
sqr x = x * x  
inc x = x + 1
```

and we want to write a function that computes x^2+1.  We can write

```
xSquaredPlusOne = inc . sqr
```

(which means

```
xSquaredPlusOne x = (inc . sqr) x
```

which means

```
xSquaredPlusOne x = inc(sqr x)
```

since f=inc and g=sqr).

Answer (score 5):

From the [HaskellWiki page on function composition:](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Function_composition)

```
desort = (reverse . sort)
```

Now `desort` is a function that sorts a list in reverse. Basically, `desort` feeds it's arguments into `sort`, and then feeds the return value from `sort` into `reverse`, an returns that. So it sorts it, and then it reverses the sorted list.

Answer (score 5):

Function composition is a way to chain two or more functions together. It's often likened to shell piping. For example, in a Unix-style shell, you might write something like

```
cat foo.txt | sort -n | less
```

This runs `cat`, feeds its output to `sort`, and feeds the output from that to `less`.

Strictly, this is like the Haskell `$` operator. You might write something like

```
sum $ sort $ filter (> 0) $ my_list
```

Notice that, unlike the shell example, this reads from right to left. So we start with `my_list` as input, then we run `filter` over it, then we `sort` it, and then we calculate the `sum` of it.

The function composition operator, `.`, does something similar. The example above produces a *number*; the example below produces a *function*:

```
sum . sort . filter (> 0)
```

Notice that we didn't actually feed a list into this. Instead, we've just created a new function, and we can feed several different lists to that function. For example, you might name this function:

```
my_function = sum . sort . filter (> 0)
```

Or you might pass it as an argument to another function:

```
map (sum . sort . filter (> 0)) my_lists
```

You can basically use it anywhere that you can use any other sort of function. It's just a quick and readable way of saying "I want to chain these functions together".