# Why the "r" in unfoldr?

Tags: haskell

Why is there an `r` in `Data.List.unfoldr`? Is it only for symmetry with `foldr`, or is there some other reason this unfolds should be considered to be right associative?

This came up when I was considering adding an unfold to `Data.HashMap`, where I couldn't think of a reason to include an `r` in the name. `HashMap`s have both right and left folds. I don't see a reason why the unfold would be more right than left.

Comment: You could imagine an `unfoldl` that builds the list the other order.  But which should be `l` or `r` is unclear to me. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In ["The Underappreciated Unfold"](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.42.1735), where `unfoldr` is introduced, it is known as `unfold` (and `foldr` is `fold`, as you [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6172270/83805)). However, by the time it made it into the List library, it had become [`unfoldr`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr), as a dual to `foldr`.

Comment: This paper now at: [The Under-Appreciated Unfold](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/unfold.ps.gz)