# How can operations like map, filter and reverse can be defined in terms of a reduce?

Tags: recursion, clojure, functional-programming, reduce, fold

In this blog entry, ["CSP and transducers in JavaScript"](http://phuu.net/2014/08/31/csp-and-transducers.html),  the author states:

> First, we have to realise that many array (or other collection) operations like `map`, `filter` and `reverse` can be defined in terms of a `reduce`.

My question is: **How can operations like map, filter and reverse can be defined in terms of a reduce?** Could you provide examples in Clojure?

Comment: This is an odd place to use `concat`, in reduce you pick your own base case, so pick the one that has the `conj` behavior needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true, if we don't care about laziness. In Clojure, `map` and `filter` are lazy, but reduce is eager. Not only is `reverse` not lazy, but the standard definition uses reduce. Modulo the laziness, we can get equivalent results for the others:

```
user> (defn eager-map [f coll]
        (reduce (fn [acc v] (conj acc (f v)))
        []
        coll))
#'user/eager-map
user> (eager-map inc (range 10))
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]

user> (defn eager-filter [f coll]
         (reduce (fn [acc v] (if (f v) (conj acc v) acc))
                 []
                 coll))
#'user/eager-filter
user> (eager-filter even? (range 10))
[0 2 4 6 8]

user> (defn eager-reverse [coll]
         (reduce conj () coll))
#'user/eager-reverse
user> (eager-reverse (range 10))
(9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0)
```

Answer (score 5):

Edited to recognize `mapv` and `filterv`.

---

The standard `reverse` *is* defined in terms of `reduce`:

```
(defn reverse [coll]
  (reduce conj () coll))
```

`map` and `filter` are lazy, so can operate on infinite sequences. There is no way to do this with `reduce`.

That being said, `reduce` can implement [`mapv`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/mapv) and [`filterv`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/filterv), the eager analogues of `map` and `filter`.

```
(defn mapv [f coll]
  (vec (reverse (reduce (fn [acc x] (cons (f x) acc)) () coll))))

(defn filterv [pred coll]
  (vec (reverse (reduce (fn [acc x] (if (pred x) (cons x acc) acc)) () coll))))
```

---

We can do without the `reverse`s and the `vec`s if we accumulate in vectors:

```
(defn mapv [f coll]
  (reduce (fn [acc x] (conj acc (f x))) [] coll))

(defn filterv [pred coll]
  (reduce (fn [acc x] (if (pred x) (conj acc x) acc)) [] coll))
```

This last is almost how the standard `filterv` is implemented.

Comment: Why the `conj` for reverse but `cons` (and outer reverse) for map/filter?

Comment: @user2864740 In `reverse`, `(defn conj [coll x] ...)` has the arguments in the correct order for `reduce`; `cons` would need to be wrapped in a function reversing its arguments: `#(cons %2 %1)`. In `map`, the `cons` inside `reduce` stacks up - hence reverses - the results, so they need to be reversed again. The same applies to `filter`. The Clojure idiom is to use a vector in such cases - avoiding the need to reverse the product. I've appended versions that do this. Note that these are returned as sequences, in case someone uses `conj` or `disj` on them.

Comment: @user2864740 the last edit invalidated some of my reply.

Answer (score 5):

> How can operations like map, filter and reverse can be defined in terms of a reduce?

This is known as the ["universality of fold"](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/fold.pdf). `fold` below is the natural fold (foldr):

Obviously, various reductions can be described via fold:

```
sum :: [Int] -> Int           product :: [Int] -> Int
sum = fold (+) 0              product = fold (*) 1

and :: [Bool] -> Bool         or :: [Bool] -> Bool
and = fold (&&) True          or = fold (||) False
```

But we can also write non-obvious reductions:

```
-- appending a list
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
(++ ys) = fold (:) ys

-- reversing a list
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
reverse = fold (\x xs -> xs ++[x]) []
```

and `map` in general:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])
map f = fold (\x xs -> f x : xs) []
```

or `filter`:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> ([a] -> [a])
filter p = fold (\x xs -> if p x then x : xs else xs) []
```

or even `fold left`:

```
foldl f v xs = fold (\x g -> (\a -> g (f a x))) id xs v
```

---

References:

1. [A tutorial on the universality and expressiveness of fold](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/fold.pdf), Graham Hutton, 1999.
2. [Writing foldl using foldr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6172270/83805), here.

Comment: it's an honour to have you answer my question. Its great all the work the Haskell guys are doing to reach out to the Clojure community. I'm working through RWH at the moment - up to Ch 7.

Comment: @hawkeye What work, hawkeye? I'm intrigued. Is Clojure Haskell's bulldog, as Huxley was Darwin's bulldog.

Comment: @Thumbnail "..undecided about purely function code, but despite this he was wholehearted in his public support of functional programming.." - seems like the analogy could work ;-)