# Clojure transducers behavior

Tags: clojure, transducer

With new clojure 1.7 I decided to understand where I can use transducers. I understand what benefit they can give, but I can't find normal examples of writing custom transducers with explanation.

Ok, I tried to test what is happening. I opened the clojure documentation. And there examples use `xf` as argument. First: what means this xf or xfrom?
This stuff produced identity transducer.

```
(defn my-identity [xf]
  (fn 
   ([]
     (println "Arity 0.")
     (xf))
   ([result]
     (println "Arity 1: " result " = " (xf result)) 
     (xf result))
   ([result input]
     (println "Arity 2: " result input " = " (xf result input)) 
     (xf result input))))
```

I took the naming of variables `[result input]` from documentation example.
I thought it's like in reduce function where `result` is reduced part and `input` is new collection element.

So when I make `(transduce my-identity + (range 5))` I got result `10` what I was expecting.
Then I read about `eduction`, but I can't understand what is it. Anyway
I made `(eduction my-identity (range 5))` and got:

```
Arity 2:  nil 0  =  nil
Arity 2:  nil 1  =  nil
Arity 1: nil  =  nil
(0 0 1 1)
```

Every item got duplicated because I call `xf` in `println` statement. 
Why it duplicated every item twice? 
Why I got nil? 
Will I always get nil while making an eduction? 
Can I relay on this behavior?

Anyway I did

```
> (reduce + (eduction my-identity (range 5))
clojure.core.Eduction cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IReduce
```

Ok, the result is a `Eduction` that is NOT reducible, but printed like a list. Why it is not reducible? When I type `(doc eduction)` I get that

```
Returns a reducible/iterable application of the transducers
to the items in coll.
```

Shouldn't `(transduce xform f coll)` and `(reduce f (eduction xfrom coll))` be the same?

I made

```
> (reduce + (sequence my-identity (range 5))
20
```

Of course I got `20` because of duplicates. Again I thought it should be
that `(transduce xform f coll)` and `(reduce f (sequence xfrom coll))` be
always equal at least in such small example without any stateful transducers. This is stupid that they are not, or I'm wrong?

Ok, then I tried `(type (sequence my-identity (range 5)))` and get
    clojure.lang.LazySeq
I thought, that it's lazy but when I tried to take the `first` element
clojure calculated all the sequence at once.

So my summary:

1) What means xf or xform?

2) Why I get `nil` as a `result` argument while `eduction` or `sequence`?

3) Could I always be sure that it will be `nil` while `eduction` or `sequence`?

4) What is `eduction` and what is the idiomatic idea it's not reducible? Or if it is, then how I can reduce it?

5) Why I get side effects while `sequence` or `eduction`?

6) Can I create actual lazy sequences with transducers?

Comment: 1) [clojure.org/transducers](http://clojure.org/transducers) - "The transducer xf is a transformation stack ..."; so, xf is a transducer (or a comp of xfs) which is _not_ a function (f) so one names it `xf`

Comment: 1) edit: should have phrased it as 'and to distinguish it from a regular function (f) one names it `xf`'

Comment: You have very interesting questions here, but I think you'll get more and better answers if you extract smaller questions from it. Q "1" could be a separate question ("What's the meaning of xf or xform in the context of transducers?"), it doesn't even need an example, the same applies to questions 4 & 6.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Many questions, let's first start with a few anwers:

1. Yes, `xf`==`xform` is a "transducer".
2. Your `my-identity` function does not compile. You have a parameter and then
   multiple other arities of the function. I believe you forgot a `(fn ...)`.
3. Your argument to your identity transducer is called `xf`. However, this is
   usually called `rf`, which means "reducing function". Now the confusing part is
   that `xf`'s are also reducing functions (hence `comp` just works). However,
   it's confusing that you'd call it `xf` and you should call it `rf`.
4. Transducers are usually "constructed" since they may be stateful and/or are
   passed parameters. In your case, you don't need to construct it since it's
   simple and doesn't have state or even a parameter. However be aware that you'd
   usually wrap your function in another `fn` returning function. This means you'd
   have to call `(my-identity)` instead of just passing it as `my-identity`.
   Again, it's fine here, just slightly unconvential and possibly confusing.
5. Let's first continue and pretend that your `my-identity` transducer is
   correct (it's not, and I'll explain later what's going on).
6. `eduction` is relatively rarely used. It creates a "process".
   I.e. you can run it over and over again and see the result. Basically, just
   like you have lists or vectors that hold your items the eduction will "hold"
   the result of the transducer applied. Note that to actually do anything you
   still need a `rf` (reducing function).
7. In the beginning I think it is helpful to think of reducing functions
   as `conj` (or actually `conj!`) or in your case `+`.
8. Your `eduction` prints the elements it produces since it implements `Iterable`
   which is called by the `println` or your REPL. It simply prints out every
   element that you add in you transducer with the arity 2 call.
9. Your call to `(reduce + (eduction my-identity (range 5)))` doesn't work
   since `Eduction` (the object being constructed in `eduction`) only implements
   `IReduceInit`. `IReduceInit` as its name suggest does **require** an initial
   value. So this will work: `(reduce + 0 (eduction my-identity (range 5)))`
10. Now if you run the above `reduce` as I suggest you'll see something very
    interesting. It prints 10. Even though your eduction earlier printed `(0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4)` (which if you add together is 20). What's going on here?
11. As stated earlier, your transducer has a flaw. It doesn't work properly. The
    problem is that you call your `rf` and then call it a second time again in your
    arity 2 function. In clojure, stuff isn't mutable, unless it's somehow
    internally mutable for optimization purposes :).
    Here the problem is that sometimes clojure uses mutation and you get duplicates
    even though you never properly capture the result of your first time you call
    `(rf)` in your arity 2 function (as the argument to your `println`).

Let's fix you function **but leave the second `rf` call in there**:

```
  (defn my-identity2 [rf]
    (fn
      ([]
       (println "Arity 0.")
       (rf))
      ([result]
       {:post [(do (println "Arity 1 " %) true)]
        :pre  [(do (println "Arity 1 " result) true)]}
       (rf result))
      ([result input]
       {:post [(do (println "Arity 2 " %) true)]
        :pre  [(do (println "Arity 2 " result input) true)]}
       (rf (rf result input) input))))
```

Note:

- I renamed `xf` to `rf` as noted earier.
- Now we can see that you use the result of you `rf` and pass it on to the
  second call of `rf`. **This transducer is not an identity transducer but
  doubles every element**

Observe carefully:

```
(transduce my-identity + (range 5));; => 10
(transduce my-identity2 + (range 5));; => 20

(count (into '() my-identity (range 200)));; => 200
(count (into  [] my-identity (range 200)));; => 400

(count (into '() my-identity2 (range 200)));; => 400
(count (into  [] my-identity2 (range 200)));; => 400

(eduction my-identity  (range 5));;=> (0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4)
(eduction my-identity2 (range 5));;=> (0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4)

(into '() my-identity  (range 5));;=> (4 3 2 1 0)
(into  [] my-identity  (range 5));;=> [0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4]
(into '() my-identity2 (range 5));;=> (4 4 3 3 2 2 1 1 0 0)


(reduce + 0 (eduction my-identity (range 5)));;=> 10
(reduce +   (sequence my-identity (range 5)));;=> 20

(reduce + 0 (eduction my-identity2 (range 5)));;=> 20
(reduce +   (sequence my-identity2 (range 5)));;=> 20
```

To aswer your questions:

1. `eduction` doesn't really pass `nil` as the `result` argument when it's being
   **reduced**. It only gets nil when being printed which calls the `Iterable`
   interface.
2. The `nil` really comes from `TransformerIterator` which is a special class
   created for transducers. This class is also used for `sequence` as you noticed.
   As the docs state:

> The resulting sequence elements are incrementally computed. These sequences
> will consume input incrementally as needed and fully realize intermediate
> operations. This behavior differs from the equivalent operations on lazy
> sequences.

The reason that you receive `nil` as the `result` argument is because an iterator has no resulting collection which holds the elements iterated over so far. It simply goes over each element. No state is being accumulated.

You can see the reducing function that is used by the `TransformerIterator` as and inner class here:

https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/TransformerIterator.java

Do a `CTRL+f` and enter `xf.invoke` to see how your transducer is getting called.

The `sequence` function isn't really as lazy as a truly lazy sequence but I
think this explains this part of you question:

[Are Clojure transducers eager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25656114/are-clojure-transducers-eager-not-lazy)

`sequence` simply computes the results of a transducer incrementally. Nothing
else.

Lastly, a proper identity function with some debug statements:

```
(defn my-identity-prop [rf]
  (fn
    ([]
     (println "Arity 0.")
     (rf))
    ([result]
     (let [r (rf result)]
       (println "my-identity(" result ") =" r)
       r))
    ([result input]
     (let [r (rf result input)]
       (println "my-idenity(" result "," input ") =" r)
       r))))
```

Comment: Thank you for such nice reply. I understand now what is happening there. 2) Yes, I forgot (fn ...) there, so if you don't mind, I'll edit my post to fix it. 3) I took the name "xf" from the http://clojure.org/transducers dedupe example. But I look at the source of clojure.core and it's named "rf" there, like you suggest, and it make more sense. At last I should be mentioned here that "sequence" calculate the sequence by chunks, it my case it is 32. That's why I didn't see it in the test with (range 5). Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I only regret that I have but one vote to give.

Comment: Wow, ive learned a lot from your answer. Btw, why did you call you arg xf and not rf in the proper identity function?