# eduction vs transducer composition

Tags: clojure, transducer

Whats the difference between:

```
(transduce (comp fn-1 fn-2 fn-3) conj vector-collection)
```

and

```
(eduction fn-1 fn-2 fn-3 vector-collection)
```

I've read the [eduction docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/eduction) but didn't understand the purpose of the eduction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`transduce` reduces the transducer by applying the reducing function to a collection. A result is calculated.

`eduction` is just stuff that remembers that you want to apply a transducer to a collection. Eduction is not itself a collection in "regular sense", but implements it's interface. So when you try to print it, it print itself like sequential.

Look here:

```
(defn my-tran [rf]
  (fn
    ([]
     (println "Arity 0!")
     (rf))
    ([res]
     (println "Arity 1!")
     (rf res))
    ([result input]
     (println "Arity 2!")
     (rf result input))))

> (def a (transduce my-tran conj '(1 2 3)))
Arity 2!
Arity 2!
Arity 2!
Arity 1!
#'test.core/a ;a is already finished

> (def r (eduction my-tran '(1 2 3)))
#'test.core/r ;nothing was done
> r 
Arity 2!
Arity 2!
Arity 2!
Arity 1!
(1 2 3) ;now it's done. Next call with calculate it again. Check it.
> (sequential? r)
true
```

So `eduction` is a partial apply of the transducer to a collection without a reducing function. But it's not `lazy-seq`. So when you `transduce` or `reduce` over `eduction` it is the same (in the sense that the same job is done at this moment, not in the sense of the result) as if you called `transduce` with a reducing function to the original collection.

See this:
[Clojure transducers behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31986435/clojure-transducers-behavior),
where there is exceptional answer which covers many questions about this idea.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helped me understand the difference :)

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a **use case for eductions** to @JustAnotherCurious' great explanation.

An `eduction` allows you to bundle one or more transducers with the collection to be transduced, into something that can be `reduce`d, but `eduction` does not perform any transductions.

`transduce` in contrast, actually reduces the collection, using the specified transducer and a reducing function.

**I use eductions in code that** creates or knows about the transducers and the collection of some operation, but **needs to stay agnostic of the reducing function**. So I can pass the result of an eduction around as a single unit, and use it someplace the reduction function is known to reduce it.

This can help you keep your aspects separated (more orthogonal code) and lead to cleaner code.