# What is a clojure Eduction?

Tags: clojure

Calling `(eduction ..)` returns in a REPL something that looks like a sequence (i.e., things like "`(1 2 3)`"). But if you check whether this return value is a sequence (via `seq?`), you get `false`.

**Question:** What exactly is an Eduction? **Is it merely a list of values that will be fed, one by one, into a reduction function?**

Comment: Probably a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31986435/clojure-transducers-behavior/31992370#31992370

Answer (score 7):

According to [transducer's doc](http://clojure.org/reference/transducers#_eduction):

> To capture the process of applying a transducer to a coll, use the eduction function. It takes any number of xforms and a final coll and returns a reducible/iterable application of the transducer to the items in coll. These applications will be performed each time reduce/iterator is called.

So it is an abstraction for applying transducers to a collection which produces something reducible/iterable. You might wonder what's the difference:

> [Seqs differ from iterators in that they are persistent and immutable, not stateful cursors into a collection](http://clojure.org/reference/sequences)

As they will go over the supplied collection apply transducers each time they are reduced/iterated over, they differ from seq's semantics.