# What does sequence do with a transducer?

Tags: clojure, transducer

Two related questions about `sequence`:

Given a transducer, e.g. `(def xf (comp (filter odd?) (map inc)))`,

1. What's the relationship between `(into [] xf (range 10))` or `(into () xf (range 10))`, and `(sequence xf (range 10))`?  Is it just that there's no syntax for a lazy sequence that can be used as the second argument of `into`, so we need a separate function `sequence` for this purpose?  (I know that `sequence` has another, non-transducer use, coercing a collection into a sequence of one kind or another.)
2. The [Clojure transducers page](http://clojure.org/reference/transducers) says, about uses of `sequence` like the one above,

> The resulting sequence elements are incrementally computed. These sequences will consume input incrementally as needed and fully realize intermediate operations. This behavior differs from the equivalent operations on lazy sequences.

To me that sounds as if `sequence` doesn't return a lazy sequence, yet the docstring for `sequence` says "When a transducer is supplied, returns a lazy sequence of applications of the transform to the items in coll(s), ....", and in fact `(class (sequence xf (range 10)))` returns `clojure.lang.LazySeq`.  I think I don't understand the last sentence quoted above from the Clojure transducers page.

Comment: I can't find it but I'm 95% sure this is a duplicate. There is a question like this here on SO.

Comment: I'd be happy to defer to that question, @ClojureMostly.  Difficult to search for.  Maybe a partial answer is buried somewhere in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31986435/clojure-transducers-behavior/31992370#31992370), but if so, it would be worth having a separate answer to my question somewhere--here or at the question I've duplicated.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25656422/1455243) to another question is also relevant, but doesn't answer my second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(sequence xform from)` creates *lazy-seq* (*RT.chunkIteratorSeq*) over *TransformerIterator* to which *xform* and *from* are passed. When next value is requested, *xform* (composition of transformations) is invoked over next value from *from*.

> This behavior differs from the equivalent operations on lazy sequences.

What would be equivalent operations on lazy sequences? With your xf as an example, 
applying `filter odd?` to `(range 10)`, producing intermediate lazy sequence, and applying `map inc` to intermediate lazy sequence, producing final lazy sequence as result.

I would say that `(into to xform from)` is similar to `(into to (sequence xform from))` when *from* is some collection which does not implement *IReduceInit*.

*into* internally uses `(transduce xform conj to from)` which does the
same as `(reduce (xform conj) to from)` and at the end *clojure.core.protocols/coll-reduce* is called:

```
(into [] (sequence xf (range 10)))
;[2 4 6 8 10]
(into [] xf (range 10))
;[2 4 6 8 10]
(transduce xf conj [] (range 10))
;[2 4 6 8 10]
(reduce (xf conj) [] (range 10))
;[2 4 6 8 10]
```

I modified a bit your transducer into:

```
(defn hof-pr
     "Prints char c on each invocation of function f within higher order function"
 ([hof f c]
   (hof (fn [e] (print c) (f e))))
 ([hof f c coll]
   (hof (fn [e] (print c) (f e)) coll)))
(def map-inc-pr (partial hof-pr map inc \m))
(def filter-odd-pr (partial hof-pr filter odd? \f))
(def xf (comp (filter-odd-pr) (map-inc-pr)))
```

so that it prints out character on each transformation step.

Create *s1* in REPL as follows:

```
(def s1 (into [] xf (range 10)))
ffmffmffmffmffm
```

*s1* is eagerly evaluated (printed f for filtering and m for mapping). No evaluation when *s1* is requested again:

```
s1
[2 4 6 8 10]
```

Let's create *s2*:

```
(def s2 (sequence xf (range 10)))
ffm
```

Only first item in *s2* is evaluated. Next items will be evaluated when requested:

```
s2
ffmffmffmffm(2 4 6 8 10)
```

Additionally, create s3, old way:

```
(def s3 (map-inc-pr (filter-odd-pr (range 10))))
s3
ffffffffffmmmmm(2 4 6 8 10)
```

As you can see, no evaluation when *s3* is defined. When *s3* is requested, filtering over 10 elements is applied and after that mapping over remaining 5 elements is applied, producing final sequence.

Comment: Beautiful, Bojan.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find the current answer clear enough, so here goes...

`sequence` does return a LazySeq, but it is a chunked one, so when you play around with it in the REPL, you will often have the impression it is eager, because your collection will probably be too small, and the chunking will make it look eager. The chunk size I think is a bit dynamic, and it won't always be exactly the same size chunks, but in general it seems to be of size 32. So your transducer will be applied to the input collection 32 elements at a time, lazily.

Here's a simple transducer that just prints the elements it reduces over and returns them untouched:

```
(defn printer
  [xf]
  (fn
    ([] (xf))
    ([result] (xf result))
    ([result input]
     (println input)
     (xf result input))))
```

If we create a sequence `s` of 100 elements with it:

```
(def s
  (sequence
   printer
   (range 100)))
;;> 0
```

We see that it prints `0`, but nothing else. On the call to `sequence`, the first element will thus be consumed from `(range 100)`, and it will be passed to the `xf` chain to be transformed, which in our case just prints it. No other elements except the first one have thus been consumed yet.

Now if we take one element from `s`:

```
(take 1 s)
;;> 0
;;> 1
;;> 2
;;> 3
;;> 4
;;> 5
;;> 6
;;> 7
;;> 8
;;> 9
;;> 10
;;> 11
;;> 12
;;> 13
;;> 14
;;> 15
;;> 16
;;> 17
;;> 18
;;> 19
;;> 20
;;> 21
;;> 22
;;> 23
;;> 24
;;> 25
;;> 26
;;> 27
;;> 28
;;> 29
;;> 30
;;> 31
;;> 32
```

We see that it printed the first 32 elements. This is the normal behavior of chunked lazy sequence in Clojure. You can think of it as semi-lazy, in that it consumes chunk-size elements at a time, instead of 1 at a time.

Now if we try to take any element from 1 to 32, nothing else will be printed, because the first 32 elements have already been processed:

```
(take 1 s)
;; => (0)
(take 10 s)
;; => (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
(take 24 s)
;; => (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23)
(take 32 s)
;; => (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31)
```

Nothing gets printed, and each take returns the expected set of result. I'm using `;; =>` for return values, and `;;>` for printed output.

Okay, now if we take the 33rd element, we expect to see the next chunk of 32 elements being printed:

```
(take 33 s)
;;> 33
;;> 34
;;> 35
;;> 36
;;> 37
;;> 38
;;> 39
;;> 40
;;> 41
;;> 42
;;> 43
;;> 44
;;> 45
;;> 46
;;> 47
;;> 48
;;> 49
;;> 50
;;> 51
;;> 52
;;> 53
;;> 54
;;> 55
;;> 56
;;> 57
;;> 58
;;> 59
;;> 60
;;> 61
;;> 62
;;> 63
;;> 64
```

Awesome! So once more, we see that only the next 32 were taken, which brings us to a total of 64 elements now processed.

Well, this demonstrates that `sequence` called with a transducer does in fact creates a lazy chunked sequence where elements will only be processed when needed (chunk-size at a time).

So what's this about?:

> The resulting sequence elements are incrementally computed. These sequences will consume input incrementally as needed and fully realize intermediate operations. This behavior differs from the equivalent operations on lazy sequences.

This is about the order in which the operations happen. With `sequence` and a transducer:

```
(sequence (comp A B C) coll)
```

Will for each elements in the chunk have them go through: `A -> B -> C`, so you get:

```
A(e1) -> B(e1) -> C(e1)
A(e2) -> B(e2) -> C(e2)
...
A(e32) -> B(e32) -> C(e32)
```

While for a normal lazy seq like:

```
(->> coll A B C)
```

Will first have all chunked elements go through A, and then have them all go through B and then C:

```
A(e1)
A(e2)
...
A(e32)
|
B(e1)
B(e2)
...
B(e32)
|
C(e1)
C(e2)
...
C(e32)
```

This requires an intermediate collection between each step, as the result of A have to be collected into a collection to then loop over and apply B, etc.

We can see this with our previous example:

```
(def s
  (sequence
   (comp (filter odd?)
         printer
         (map vector)
         printer)
   (range 10)))

(take 1 s)
;;> 1
;;> [1]
;;> 3
;;> [3]
;;> 5
;;> [5]
;;> 7
;;> [7]
;;> 9
;;> [9]


(def l
  (->> (range 10)
       (filter odd?)
       (map #(do (println %) %))
       (map vector)
       (map #(do (println %) %))))

(take 1 l)
;;> 1
;;> 3
;;> 5
;;> 7
;;> 9
;;> [1]
;;> [3]
;;> [5]
;;> [7]
;;> [9]
```

See how the first will `filter -> vector -> filter -> vector, etc.` While the second will `filter all -> vector all`. Well this is what the quote from the doc means.

Now one more thing, there is a difference in how the chunking is applied as well between the two. With `sequence` and a transducer, it will process elements until the transducer result has chunk-size count of elements. While in the lazy-seq case, it will process in chunks at each level until all steps have enough for what they need to do.

Here's what I mean:

```
(def s
  (sequence
   (comp printer
         (filter odd?))
   (range 100)))

(take 1 s)
;;> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65

(def l
  (->> (range 100)
       (map #(do (print % "") %))
       (filter odd?)))

(take 1 l)
;;> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Here I modified the printing logic to be on the same line, so it doesn't take as much space. And if you look closely, `s` processed 66 elements of the input range, while `l` only consumed 32 elements.

The reason for this is what I said above. With `sequence`, we will continue taking in chunks until we have chunk-size number of results. In this case, the chunk-size is 32, and since we filter on `odd?`, it takes us two chunks to reach 32 results.

With lazy-seq, it doesn't try and grab the first chunk of results, but only enough chunks from the input to satisfy the logic, in this case, that only needs one chunk of 32 elements from the input for us to find a single odd number to take.