# Is flatmap/mapcat a function that can be used as the basis of other higher order functions?

Tags: dictionary, clojure, fold, higher-order-functions, flatmap

We can see that we can use `reduce`/`foldl1` as the function by which [we can define other higher order functions such as map, filter and reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654696/how-can-operations-like-map-filter-and-reverse-can-be-defined-in-terms-of-a-red).

```
(defn mapl [f coll]
  (reduce (fn [r x] (conj r (f x)))
          [] coll))

(defn filterl [pred coll]
  (reduce (fn [r x] (if (pred x) (conj r x) r))
          [] coll))

(defn mapcatl [f coll]
  (reduce (fn [r x] (reduce conj r (f x)))
          [] coll))
```

We also appear to be able to do this in terms of `foldr`. Here is `map` and `filter` in terms of [`foldr` from Rich Hickey's Transducers talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mTbuzafcII) at 17:25.

```
(defn mapr [f coll]
  (foldr (fn [x r] (cons (f x) r))
         () coll))

(defn filterr [pred coll]
  (foldr (fn [x r] (if (pred x) (cons x r) r))
         () coll))
```

Now it turns out there are some papers that explain this:

BIRD - Lectures on Constructive Functional Programming - 1988
https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/3390/PRG69.pdf

HUTTON - A tutorial on the universality and expressiveness of fold - 1999
http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/fold.pdf

Now I heard somebody say this week:

> well `flatmap` (`mapcat`) is fundamental - you can express lots of higher order functions in terms of it.

So here is `map` implemented in terms of mapcat.

```
=> (defn mymap [f coll] (mapcat (comp vector f) coll))

=> (mymap #(+ 1 %) (range 0 9))

(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

But to me that feels artificial since you're really just boxing things and working out whether map itself is 'fundamental'.

The reason this last example feels a little artificial is that mapcat is already defined in terms of map. If you look at the [source for mapcat](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.6.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2580) - we see something similar to:

```
(defn mapcat
  [f & colls]
    (apply concat (apply map f colls)))
```

So the example above merely reverses out the concat and reuses the underlying definition of map inside of mapcat - which to me feels artificial. Now it would be ok if mapcat could be used to define other HOFs - but I don't know how to do that - and I'm hoping someone can point me in that direction.

My question is: **Is flatmap/mapcat a function that can be used as the basis of other higher order functions?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` is a primitive used to create `mapcat`.

You can use `mapcat` to create `map` which is reducing `mapcat` back to the `map` it was built from.

You can build an infinite amount of higher order functions using both.

Comment: Thanks! Could you give an example of building a HOF?

Comment: Every function that takes a function as a parameter is a higher order function.