# Haskell foldl implementation with foldr

Tags: haskell

I have troubles understanding the implementation of the `foldl` function using `foldr`. I have read this question ([Writing foldl using foldr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172004/writing-foldl-using-foldr)) and I still have some things I don't understand in the following example:

```
fun :: [Int] -> [Int]
fun l = foldr g (const []) l 1
    where g x f lst = if gcd x lst == 1 then x : f x else f lst
```

The function takes a list as parameter and return another list where `gcd(l[i], l[i + 1] = 1`.

My questions are the following:
1. Who are `x`, `f` and `lst`
2. What is `const[]` and why I can't use the `id` function?

Comment: 1: parameters of your `g` function, 2. `const x = \y -> x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foldr` is one of those weird tools like bicycles that are really easy to use once you get the hang of them but hard to learn from the start. After several years of experience, I've gotten really good at spotting problems I can solve with `foldr`, and solving them with it immediately and correctly, but it could easily take me a while to figure out what just what I've done in enough detail to explain!

From a practical standpoint, I usually think of `foldr` in vaguely continuation-passing language. Ignoring the "simple" case where `foldr` is only applied to three arguments, an application of `foldr` looks like this:

```
foldr go finish xs acc1 acc2 ... where
  finish acc1 acc2 ... = ?
  go x cont acc1 acc2 ... = ?
```

`acc1`, etc., are accumulators passed "from left to right". The result consists, conceptually, of a single value passed "from right to left".

`finish` gets the final values of the accumulators and produces something of the result type. It's usually the easiest part to write because

```
foldr go finish [] acc1 acc2 ...
=
finish acc1 acc2 ...
```

So once you figure out just what you want your fold to produce, writing `finish` is fairly mechanical.

`go` gets a single container element, a "continuation", and the accumulators. It passes modified values if those accumulators "forward" to the continuation to get a result, and uses that result to construct its own.

`foldl` is a particularly simple case because its `go` function just returns the result it gets from folding the rest of the container with a new accumulator argument. I think it's a bit more instructive to look at an example that does a bit more. Here's one that takes a container of numbers and produces a list of pairs representing a running sum and a running product.

```
sumsProducts :: (Num n, Foldable f) => f n -> [(n, n)]
sumsProducts xs = foldr go finish xs 0 1
  where
    finish total prod = [(total, prod)]
    go x cont total prod =
      (total, prod) : cont (x + total) (x * prod)
```

Answer (score 1):

`foldr`'s type signature is this

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

This means your `foldr` applied to its 3 arguments must return a function that takes the `1` as an argument.

So you can specialise your `foldr` to this

```
foldr :: (Int -> (Int -> [Int]) -> (Int -> [Int])) 
        -> (Int -> [Int]) 
        -> [Int]
        -> (Int -> [Int])
```

This means your `g` function must have the following type

```
g :: Int -> (Int -> [Int]) -> Int -> [Int]
```

So your parameters have the type

```
x   :: Int
f    :: Int -> [Int]
lst :: Int
```

And `foldr` in its 2nd argument requires a `Int -> [Int]` instead of just an `Int`, so you can't pass it the value `[]`.

Fortunately `const` returns a function that ignores its argument and just always return a constant expression

```
const [] :: a -> [b]
```

In your case `f` is indeed some kind of accumulator. But instead of reducing e.g. a list of values to some number, you are chaining functions here. By passing `1` to this function chain in the end, it gets evaluated and is then building the actual list you return in `fun`.

Comment: But isn't g's type only `g :: Int -> (Int -> [Int]) -> Int -> [Int]` so `x :: Int` , `f :: Int -> [Int]` and `lst :: Int`? Because `gcd` should take as aruguments two integers in `gcd x lst`. And I am still wondering how the foldr works with the `const[]` function. Is it supposed to be some kind of and accumulator?

Comment: Wow, I totally screwed the types up. Thanks for pointing it out! You are accumulating a chain of functions here.