# Why it is not possible to redefine (implement) foldr in terms of foldl

Tags: haskell, fold, proof

We have that [`foldl` can be implemented in terms of `foldr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172004/writing-foldl-using-foldr). This is explained in detail in [A tutorial on the universality and expressiveness of fold](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/fold.pdf). In the paper it is stated that:

> In contrast, it is not possible to redefine `fold` in terms of `foldl` , due to the fact that `foldl` is strict in the tail of its list argument but `fold` is not.

However I fail to see how this constitutes a proof on the impossibility of defining `foldr` in terms of `foldl` (note that in the original paper `fold` is a synonym for `foldr`). I'm quite puzzled trying to understand how strictness plays a role here. Can somebody expand on this explanation?

Comment: Consider a safe version of `head`: `safeHead = foldr (\x y -> Just x <|> y) Nothing` (and import `Control.Applicative`). If you use the version of `foldr` defined with `foldl`, `safeHead [1..]` won't terminate. With the usual `foldr`, it will immediately return `Just 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In what follows, I will refer to `fold` as `foldr` (since that is what its is called in the Haskell standard libraries).

---

Taking another look at the definition of `foldl`,

```
foldl :: (β -> α -> β) -> β -> [α] -> β
foldl f v [] = v
foldl f v (x:xs) = foldl f (f v x) xs
```

note that the base case requires the list argument to be `[]` - in all other cases the list is evaluated to WNHF and we recurse immediately using the tail of the list. That establishes the fact that `foldl` is strict in its (last) list argument.

Now, we *can* write a version of `foldr` using `foldl`, but it will only work on lists of finite length. See [this page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldl_as_foldr) for the motivation.

```
foldr' :: (α -> β -> β) -> β -> [α] -> β
foldr' f v xs = foldl (\g u x -> g (f u x)) id xs v
```

To see the problem, let's try to write a version of `head` which is total<sup>1</sup> using a right fold.

```
import Control.Applicative ((<|>))

safeHead :: [α] -> Maybe α
safeHead = foldr (\x y -> Just x <|> y) Nothing
```

If we replace `foldr` with our `foldl`-based `foldr'`, we are no longer able to find the head of an infinite list `safeHead [1..]`. Even if `safeHead` only needs to look at the first element of the list, the underlying `foldl` will try to traverse the whole infinite list.

---

<sup>1</sup> Such a function actually already exists in the Prelude, it is called [listToMaybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:listToMaybe)

Answer (score 5):

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f acc [] = acc
foldr f acc (x : xs) = f x (foldr f acc xs)
```

Note that when the list isn't empty, the recursive call to `foldr` is *inside* an argument passed to `f`. Haskell is lazily evaluated, so that recursive call to `foldr` isn't necessarily actually computed. If `f` can return a result without examining the second argument (but it **can** examine the first argument `x` to *decide* whether or not it wants to look at its second argument), then the `foldr` call can "stop early", without examining the whole list.

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl f acc [] = acc
foldl f acc (x : xs) = foldl (f acc x) xs
```

Here (when the list isn't empty) `foldl` recurses immediately, with the call to `f` inside the accumulator argument it passes to the recursive call. `f` doesn't get the opportunity to decide whether to examine the recursive call or not; `foldl` is in complete control of how long to keep recursing for, and it keeps doing so until it finds the end of the list.

So in particular, with `foldr` you can potentially process an infinite list; so long as the function you pass it eventually doesn't reference its second argument (`acc`). For example in GHCi:

```
Prelude> foldr (\x acc -> if x > 10 then "..." else show x ++ ", " ++ acc) "STOP" [1..5]
"1, 2, 3, 4, 5, STOP"

Prelude> foldr (\x acc -> if x > 10 then "..." else show x ++ ", " ++ acc) "STOP" [1..]
"1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ..."
```

With `foldr`, the lambda function is able to use that `if` statement to examine the list element `x` and decide whether or not to use the results of folding the rest of the list (which are referenced by `acc` but haven't actually been computed yet).

Alternatively, the function could return a result including the recursive call but store it in the field of a data constructor. This means the `foldr` will produce an infinitely nested data structure, but allows the *caller* of `foldr` to decide how much of that infinite structure it wants to look at, so the caller might still be able to return a finite result processing it. An example would be:

```
Prelude> take 10 $ foldr (\x acc -> x + 100 : acc) [] [1..]
[101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110]
```

Here I'm just using `foldr` to do the same job as `map`, adding 100 to each element of the infinite list, which produces an infinite list in turn, but then `take 10` only grabs the first 10 of them. This works because the infinite "results of folding the result of the list" are simply stored in the second field of the list constructor `:`.

That ability to process an infinite list (whether you actually return a finite or infinite result) can't be simulated by `foldl`, because the function you pass into `foldl` doesn't get to decide "how much" of the recursion to use; `foldl` itself recurses all the way to the end of the list before it returns anything other than another call to `foldl`. If the list is infinite it simply never returns anything other than another call to `foldl`, no matter what function you pass to `foldl` or what wrapper you use to try to make it do the job of `foldr`.

It's not just about processing infinite lists either (if that seems esoteric); if all your lists are finite then you *can* use `foldl` to get the same results as `foldr` but you're still locked into examining the entire list, which can be very inefficient if you only actually needed a small prefix of it.