# Defining foldl in terms of foldr

Tags: haskell, fold, foldleft

```
myFoldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a

myFoldl f z xs = foldr step id xs z
    where step x g a = g (f a x)
```

I am currently reading a book on Haskell. And in it, it wrote its own version of the foldl function, but in terms of foldr. I do not follow.

1. Why are there 4 arguments for foldr?
2. What does the id function do?

Comment: This is mindbending for me, but the long and short of it is that there *aren't* 4 arguments for foldr. This is `(foldr step id xs) $ z` where the `foldr` builds a chain of functions applied to each other.

Comment: Well, it's Haskell.  There's no difference between a 4-argument function and a 3-argument function that returns a 1-argument function.

Comment: The id function is initial case of foldr, that is, say, when xs is [], then give me a id function.

Comment: same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172004/writing-foldl-using-foldr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing foldl using foldr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172004/writing-foldl-using-foldr)

Answer (score 3):

The thing will be become obvious when to expand the expression of `foldr step id xs z`:

As Adam Smith said in the comments:

> foldr step id xs z = (foldr step id xs) z

Consider `foldr step id xs` firstly

```
foldr step id xs
= x1 `step` (foldr step id xs1)
= x1 `step` (x2 `step` (foldr step id xs2))
...
= x1 `step` (x2 `step` ... (xn `step` (foldr step id []))...)
= x1 `step` (x2 `step` ... (xn `step` id)...)
```

where

```
xs = (x1:xs1)
xs1 = (x2:xs2), xs = (x1:x2:xs2) 
....
xsn = (xn:[]), xs = (x1:x2...xsn) respectively
```

Now, apply above function with argument z, i.e.

```
(x1 `step` (x2 `step` ... (xn `step` id)...)) z
```

and let

```
g = (x2 `step` ... (xn `step` id)...)
```

gives

```
(x1 `step` g) z
```

i.e.

```
(step x1 g) z
```

and now apply the where part of foldl:

> where step x g a = g (f a x)

gives

```
(step x1 g) z = step x1 g z = g (step z x1)
```

where

```
g (step z x1) = (x2 `step` (x3 step ... (xn `step` id)...) (step z x1)
```

let

```
g' = (x3 step ... (xn `step` id)...)
```

gives

```
(x2 `step` g') (step z x1)
= step x2 g' (step z x1)
= g' (step (step z x1) x2))
= (x3 step ... (xn `step` id)...) (step (step z x1) x2))
```

repeats the same steps, finally we have,

```
(xn `step` id) (step ....(step (step z x1) x2)....)
= step xn id (step ....(step (step z x1) x2)....)
= id (step (step ....(step (step z x1) x2)....) xn)
= (step (step ....(step (step z x1) x2)....) xn)
= foldl step z xs
```

and now, it is obvious that why use id function. finally, see why

```
foldl step z xs = (step (step ....(step (step z x1) x2)....) xn)
```

initial case:

```
foldl step z' [] = z'
```

recursive case:

```
foldl step z (x1:xs1) 
= foldl step (step z x1) xs1
= foldl step (step (step z x1) x2) xs2
...
= foldl step (step (step ....(step (step z x1) x2)....) xn) []
= (step (step ....(step (step z x1) x2)....) xn)
```

where

```
z' = (step (step ....(step (step z x1) x2)....) xn) in initial case
```

Just same as above.

Answer (score 1):

As [Adam Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3058609/adam-smith) says in the comments, there are only three arguments to `foldr`. The line in question gets parsed like this:

```
myFoldl f z xs = (foldr step id xs) z
```

There are other implicit brackets too of course, but these are the important ones.

Here is a rewrite with the type annotations, assuming scoped type variables (i.e. `a` and `b` mean the same types throughout this definition).

```
myFoldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
myFoldl f z xs =  goFold z
   where
      goFold :: a -> a
      goFold = foldr step id xs
      step :: b -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)  -- Last brackets are redundant
      step x g a = g (f a x)
```

I've moved the `foldr` invocation into a separate value `goFold` so you can see its type and how it gets applied to the `z` value. The `step` function accumulates the `b` values into a function of type `(a -> a)`. Each `b` value processed by `goFold` adds an extra one of these. The "zero" for functions is of course `id` from the Prelude:

```
id :: a -> a
id x = x
```

The `->` function operator in the types is right associative, so the last pair of brackets in the `step` type are redundant. But I've written it like that because it higlights the way in which `step` is being used; it takes a value and a function and returns a new function.