# Finding head of a list using foldl and the last element using foldr

Tags: haskell, fold

It is known that we can find *head* of a list using `foldr` like this:

```
head'' :: [a] -> a
head'' = foldr (\x _ -> x) undefined
```

but, is there any way to get the same result using ***`foldl`***?

Similarly, we can find the *last* element of list using `foldl` like this:

```
last'' :: [a] -> a
last'' = foldl (\_ x -> x) undefined
```

Is there any way to get the same result using ***`foldr`***?

Comment: [`foldl` can be defined in terms of `foldr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53057923/defining-foldl-in-terms-of-foldr), so yes.

Comment: [`foldr` can also be written in terms of `foldl`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldl_as_foldr), but only for finite lists.

Answer (score 3):

`head` cannot be written with `foldl`, because `foldl` goes into an infinite loop on infinite lists, while `head` doesn't. Otherwise, sure:

```
head' :: [a] -> a
head' = fromJust . foldl (\y x -> y <|> Just x) Nothing
```

Drop the `fromJust` for a safe version.

`last` can definitely be written as a `foldr`, in about the same way:

```
last' :: [a] -> a
last' = fromJust . foldr (\x y -> y <|> Just x) Nothing
```

For `head`, we start with `Nothing`. The first element (the wanted one) is wrapped into `Just` and used to "override" the `Nothing` with `(<|>)`. The following elements are ignored. For `last`, it's about the same, but flipped.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that springs to mind is to use `foldl1` instead of `foldl`, then:

```
head'' :: [a] -> a
head'' = foldl1 (\x _ -> x)
```

and since `foldl1` is defined in terms of `foldl` if the list is non-empty (and crashes if the list is empty - but so does `head`):

```
foldl1 f (x:xs) = foldl f x xs
```

we can say

```
head'' (x:xs) = foldl (\x _ -> x) x xs
```

The same of course for `last`, using `foldr1`

Comment: Surely [`foldl1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#foldl1) and [`foldr1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#foldr1) are cheating?

Comment: In a sense, yes - but since they can be rewritten in terms of "plain" `foldl` and `foldr` (except for empty lists, but then `head` and `tail` crash too) I don't see how you can say this isn't a solution. It's not particularly clear what motivates the OP's question, other than simple curiosity, so I can't say whether this is acceptable or not. But it seems ok to me.