# Re-write 'map intToDigit' with a fold...

Tags: haskell

So this one seems like it should be super-simple... but I'm not sure where to stick the 'fold' in (obviously you could fold either way)...

It says "write a function ( `intToString :: [Int] -> [Char]` ) using a fold, that mimics this map:

`map intToDigit [5,2,8,3,4] == "52834"`

And then says, "For the conversion, use `intToDigit :: Int -> Char` from `Data.Char`."

I'm not entirely sure I get the point... but yet it doesn't seem like it should be that hard -- you're just reading in the list (folding it in, I get how folds work in general) from either the left or right and doing the conversion... but I'm not sure how to set it up.

Comment: Tip: think about foldr step [] xs ... use foldr and function (:) to construct a list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not difficult, think about the definition `foldr` (or `foldl`) of List:

```
 foldr::(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

Here `(a->b->b)` is the `step` function which will be applied on each element of list [a], b is your target.

Now, you have a list of Int (`[Int]`), and need to convert to [Char] (or String).

Relpace `[a]` by `[5,2,8,3,4]`, b by `[]::[Char]` (your target) and `(a->b->b)` by `step` function :

```
foldr step ([]::[Char]) [5,2,8,3,4]
```

We have known that `step function` has type `(a->b->b)`, specifically, `(Int->[Char]->[Char])`, the job need to do just convert `Int` to `[Char]`, as mentioned in question: `intToDigit` can be helped to convert `Int` to `Char` and `(:)` operator can append element at the head of `List` so:

```
step x s = intToDigit x : s
```

where s is `[Char]` (or `String`), put them all:

```
foldr (\x s->intToDigit x : s) [] [5,2,8,3,4]
```

Comment: Aha!  I didn't think it was *that* difficult, but for some reason I just couldn't get it put together correctly and just kept getting more confused.  Thanks for helping straighten out my brain!  

Playing around with it a little I could use it as a stand-alone lambda expression or in a function and changed it to use a `foldl` too.  I am loving learning Haskell!

Comment: @Stormy Yes, Haskell is funny! Actually, foldl can be implemented by foldr, learning that can understand them in deep, if you have interested, see [Defining foldl in terms of foldr] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172004/writing-foldl-using-foldr