# Lattice paths algorithm using recursion schemes

Tags: haskell, recursion-schemes

I'm playing around with some recursion schemes, namely catamorphisms and anamorphisms, and would like to try to implement a solution to the lattice paths algorithm as described below using them (taken from a collection of interview questions):

```
Prompt:  Count the number of unique paths to travel from the top left
          order to the bottom right corner of a lattice of M x N squares.

          When moving through the lattice, one can only travel to the
          adjacent corner on the right or down.

 Input:   m {Integer} - rows of squares
 Input:   n {Integer} - column of squares
 Output:  {Integer}

 Example: input: (2, 3)

          (2 x 3 lattice of squares)
           __ __ __
          |__|__|__|
          |__|__|__|

          output: 10 (number of unique paths from top left corner to bottom right)**
```

Using normal recursion, you could solve this with something like:

```
lattice_paths m n =
         if m == 0 and n == 0 then 1
         else if m < 0 or n < 0 then 0
         else (lattice_paths (m - 1) n) + lattice_paths m (n - 1)
```

My `Fix`, `cata` and `ana` are defined as follows:

```
newtype Fix f = In (f (Fix f))

deriving instance (Eq (f (Fix f))) => Eq (Fix f)
deriving instance (Ord (f (Fix f))) => Ord (Fix f)
deriving instance (Show (f (Fix f))) => Show (Fix f)

out :: Fix f -> f (Fix f)
out (In f) = f

-- Catamorphism
type Algebra f a = f a -> a

cata :: (Functor f) => Algebra f a -> Fix f -> a
cata f = f . fmap (cata f) . out

-- Anamorphism
type Coalgebra f a = a -> f a

ana :: (Functor f) => Coalgebra f a -> a -> Fix f
ana f = In . fmap (ana f) . f
```

The approach mentioned in this post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56012344) for writing recursion schemes that go from Int -> Int, is to write a hylomorphism where the anamorphism sort of builds the call stack and the catamorphism the evaluation of said callstack. I'm not sure how to build the call stack here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
data CallStack a = Plus a a | Base Int deriving Functor

produceStack :: Coalgebra CallStack (Int, Int)
produceStack (m, n) =
    if m == 0 && n == 0 then Base 1
    else if m < 0 || n < 0 then Base 0
    else Plus (m-1, n) (m, n-1)

consumeStack :: Algebra CallStack Int
consumeStack (Base n) = n
consumeStack (Plus a b) = a + b
```

"Stack" is a funny name for this call structure. It's not very stack-like.

Comment: Suggest demonstrating guards as an alternative to if/else as a more idiomatic way of accomplishing this.

Comment: This solves the question as asked, but it's terribly inefficient for large N, isn't it? Because it doesn't cache results from the middle of the table, it ends up recomputing them many times.

Comment: @amalloy Oh, of course a *good* solution involves defining the standard `choose` operation from combinatorics, then writing ```lattice_paths m n = (m+n) `choose` m``` (possibly off-by-one there on `m` and `n`, I didn't check carefully). I understood the question to be about what the patterns of translating from direct recursion to recursion schemes look like, hence the attempt to keep as much of the original code structure as possible.

Comment: Interesting, will the haskell compiler not memoize the results of previous computations here?

Comment: @cocorudeboy https://stackoverflow.com/q/3951012/791604