# What does . (dot) stand for?

Tags: haskell

What does `.` (dot) stand for? For example it is used in `sumDigits` but I don't understand what it does.

```
toDigits m = loop m [] where
    loop x y | x <= 0    = y
             | otherwise = loop (x `div` 10) ((x `mod` 10) : y)

sumDigits = sum . map (sum . toDigits)
```

Comment: on StackOverflow, question edits must not invalidate the answers.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I don't understand this either. it's not like Haskell has a _proper_ [clickable documentation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Front/X_Mast_9.htm) or something, which the OP could've easily explored. (one can even search for "dot" on that page... oh my)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dot `(.)` is an infix operator. It is defined so that

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)
```

Thus,

```
sumDigits     =   sum . map (sum . toDigits)
= {- by "eta-expansion" -}
sumDigits xs  =  (sum . map (sum . toDigits))    xs
              = {- by definition of (.) -}
                 sum ( map (sum . toDigits)      xs )
              = {- re-writing as list comprehension -}
                 sum [ (sum . toDigits) x | x <- xs ]
              = {- by definition of (.) -}
                 sum [ sum ( toDigits x ) | x <- xs ]
```

which should be clear enough.

But you should always add type signatures to your top-level definitions in any case. Here you have

```
toDigits :: Integral a => a -> [a]

sumDigits :: Integral c => [c] -> c
```

These provide at least partial documentation for us: `toDigits` turns an integral number into a list of integral numbers, and `sumDigits` goes the other way around. How exactly do they do that, these types do not say; but they do provide a general outline of what's going on.

Answer (score 8):

The `.` stands for [function composition](https://wiki.haskell.org/Function_composition) in Haskell.

It allows you to chain different functions. In your case, instead of doing a new function that calls `toDigits` and then `sum` over the result, you can use function composition.

```hs
sumDigits = sum (map myFunction)

myFunction xs = sum (toDigits xs)
```

The definition of `.` is the following.

```hs
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c  
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

There's a really good example on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475896/haskell-function-composition) already you can check.

> Say you have these functions:
>
> ```
> even :: Int -> Bool
> not :: Bool -> Bool
> ```
>
> and you want to define your own `myOdd :: Int -> Bool` function using
> the two above.
>
> The obvious way to do this is the following:
>
> ```
> myOdd :: Int -> Bool myOdd x = not (even x)
> ```
>
> But this can be done more succinctly using function composition:
>
> ```
> myOdd :: Int -> Bool myOdd = not . even
> ```
>
> The myOdd functions behave exactly the same, but the second one is
> created by "glue-ing" two functions together.

Comment: thankyou! Could you please explain me this function ? I want to know what it is doing with 1:2:. Thanks!
doubleEveryOther = reverse . zipWith (*) value . reverse  where
    value = 1 : 2 : value

Comment: `value = 1 : 2 : value` makes the infinite list `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, ...]`.
`doubleEveryOther` grabs a list, reverses it, then pairs every item in the two lists and multiplies them together, then reverses the list again to return it.

Comment: You can think of the order of operations as the inverse of the order of compositions, the last `reverse` is called first, then the `zipWith` in the middle, then the first `reverse`.

Answer (score 3):

The [**`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:.) is [*function composition* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition): It takes two functions `f` and `g`, and for a value `x`, it will return `f (g x)`. In mathematics this is denoted as *f ∘ g*: it produces a function that first applies *g* and then applies *f* on the result of *g*.

In this specific case it will thus first apply `map (sum . toDigits)` before calling `sum` on the result. and for the mapping itself it will for each item in the list first call `toDigits` before applying `sum`. It will thus for a list of numbers determine the sum of the sum of the digits.